# Set children background color list

Tags: jquery, list, html-lists, background-color

I have a lit like this:

```
 <ul id="categoria"> <br>
    <li><a href="#">Categoria1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Categoria2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Esercizio1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Esercizio2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Categoria3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Categoria4</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Esercizio1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Esercizio2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Categoria5</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to set the background color, for example red , but just for the children of the list. So in this case Esercizio1, Esercizio2, ecc. with jquery. How is possible to do it? I only know to do for  the whole list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:
**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/6rSQ4/)**

```
$(".sub-menu li > a").css('background-color','red');
```

Comment: @user2556079, nice to hear :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$('.sub-menu li').css('background', 'red');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do that like this:

```
$('element').children().css({'background-color':'red'});
```

in your case:

```
$('ul li').children().css({'background-color':'red'});
```

a more detailed version:

```
$(".elementClassName li").children().css({'background-color':'red'});
```

you can specify for example only p tag children:

```
$(".elementClassName li").children('p').css({'background-color':'red'});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this selector.

```
$("#categoria li ul li > a").css({backgroundColor: "red" });
```

or

```
$(".sub-menu li > a").css({backgroundColor: "red" });
```

[See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/exM9K/)

You can learn about [jQuery selectors here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

---

This can also be achieved using CSS:

```
#categoria li ul li > a { background-color: red; }
```

or

```
.sub-menu li > a { background-color: red; }
```